# Update через цикл While

Tags: sql, sql-server

Подскажите пожалуйста:
Есть таблица t1 в ней есть поля допустим ID, FirstValue, SecondValue

```
ID  FirstValue    SecondValue
 1     null         1.1 клиент
 2     null         Вася
 3     null         Петя
 4     null         1.2 партнеры
 5     null         Газпром
 6     null         USA
```

нужно проитерировать чтоб получился такой результат,только не курсором а циклом:

```
ID     FirstValue        SecondValue
 1     1.1 клиент         1.1 клиент
 2     1.1 клиент         Вася
 3     1.1 клиент         Петя
 4     1.2 партнеры       1.2 партнеры
 5     1.2 партнеры       Газпром
 6     1.2 партнеры       USA
```

Подскажите как? можно на словах)

Comment: Если циклом, то причем тут sql ? в sql нет никаких циклов. А если все таки sql, то нужно знать какой именно диалект, например поддерживает ли он CTE, оконные функции или может это старые версии mysql с переменными. А еще надо бы знать точное правило по которому понять, что в firstValue пора ставить новое значение. Сейчас подчиненности в исходной таблице не прослеживается. Значения для firstValue никак от остальных не отличаются, кроме как наличием цифр в начале

Comment: Обычный однотабличный UPDATE с кляузой сортировки по убыванию `ID`. Значение для обновления получаете в коррелированном подзапросе - отбираете записи по шаблону наименования группы и непревышению `ID`, и берёте первую при сортировке по убыванию `ID`. Просто и плоско. Можно, конечно, и многотаблично, но у него нет сортировки, и, значит, плюс ещё одна копия таблицы - нафиг.

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался спасибо!

```
   set nocount on
   if isnull(object_id('tempdb..#t1'),0) <> 0
     drop table #t1

    create table #t1 (
                     ID          int identity(1,1),
                     FirstValue  varchar(20),
                     SecondValue varchar(20)
                     )

    insert into #t1 (FirstValue, SecondValue)
    select '', '1.1 Клиенты'  union all
    select '', 'Клиент 1'     union all
    select '', 'Клиент 2'     union all
    select '', 'Клиент 3'     union all
    select '', '1.2 Партнеры' union all
    select '', 'Партнер 1'    union all
    select '', 'Партнер 2'    union all
    select '', 'Партнер 3'    

    begin tran

    declare @ID          int,
            @SecondValue varchar(20)

    select @ID          = 0,
           @SecondValue = ''

    while 1 = 1
    begin
    select @ID = min(ID)
      from #t1
     where ID > @ID
    if @ID is null break

    select @SecondValue = SecondValue
      from #t1
     where ID = @ID

    if isnull(@SecondValue,'') <> ''
    begin
      update #t1
      set FirstValue = (
                        select top 1 SecondValue
                          from #t1
                         where ID <= @ID
                           and SecondValue like '1.%'
                        order by ID desc
                       )
      where ID = @ID
    end
    end

    rollback
```

Получается:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Посмотрите в строну оконок и 2 вложенных запросов. Можно сделать без цикла. Если таблица у вас маленькая, можете и так оставить...